# Spivak 22-32(a)

Tags: real-analysis

Question is from Chapter 22 of Spivak's calculus:

[image]

The solution is (incomplete):
[image]

My issue is with the last sentence starting "Of course...".  It seems that $\#(1)+\cdots+\#(n)=N(1+\cdots+n;a,b)$ is not quite right.  The RHS is really the count of all fractions up to $n+1$, but the LHS is the count only up to $n$.  Am I correct?  Finally if that solution were correct, would it suffice to simply substitute $m=1+\cdots+n$ where $m \to \infty$ as $1+\cdots+n \to \infty$ and conclude what needs to be proven instead with $m$?

EDIT:  Someone has confirmed that $\#(1)+\cdots+\#(n)=N(1+\cdots+n;a,b)$ is incorrect.  I suspect the proper equation is $\#(1)+\cdots+\#(n)=N(1+\cdots+n-1;a,b)$.  I believe the proof will still work.  But can someone supply the rest of the proof so that we have the final result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you is it that you state that “[t]he LHS is really the count of all fractions up to $n+1$”. Take $n=1$. The number $\#(1)$ is the number of all numbers $j$ such that $\frac j1=j\in[a,b]$. And the RHS is $N(1;a,b)$, which is the same number. Don't you agree?

On the other hand, after proving that the statement in the particular case of the numbers of the type $1+2+\cdots+n$, *something* must be aded. Otherwise, the statement would have been proved only for a subsequence of the sequence of the naturals.

Comment: Sorry I got the RHS and LHS mixed up before.  Take $n=3$ then the LHS is the count for denominators 1,2,3.  But if you look at the RHS, we have $N(6;a,b)$ which is the first 6 entries in the sequence, the last three of the 6 has denominator 4.$

Comment: Is my above comment wrong?

Comment: @helios321 I see nothing wrong with it and I hope that someone else will answer your question.